# Alternatively train multi task learning model in pytorch - weight updating

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I want to build a multi task learning model on two related datasets with different inputs and targets. The two tasks are sharing lower-level layers but with different header layers, a minimal example:

```py
class MultiMLP(nn.Module):
    """
    A simple dense network for MTL on hard parameter sharing.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(100, 200)
        self.out_task0= nn.Linear(200, 1)
        self.out_task0= nn.Linear(200, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.hidden(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        y_task0 = self.out_task0(x)
        y_task1 = self.out_task1(x)
        return [y_task0, y_task1]
```

The dataloader is constructed so that the batches are alternatively generated from two datasets, i.e. *batch 0, 2, 4, ...* from *task 0*, *batch 1, 3, 5, ...* from *task 1*.  I wanted to train the network in this way: only update weights for `hidden` layer and `out_task0` for batches from *task 0*, and update only `hidden` and `out_task1` for *task 1*.

I then alternatively switch `requires_grad` for the corresponding tasks during training as following. **But I observed that all weights are updated for every iteration.**

```py
...
criterion = MSELoss()
for i, data in enumerate(combined_loader):
    x, y = data[0], data[1]    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # controller is 0 for task0, 1 for task1
    # altenate the header layer
    controller = i % 2
    task0_mode = True if controller == 0 else False
    for name, param in model.named_parameters():
        if name in ['out_task0.weight', 'out_task0.bias']:
            param.requires_grad = task0_mode
        elif name in ['out_task1.weight', 'out_task1.bias']:
            param.requires_grad = not task0_mode

    outputs = model(x)[controller]
    loss = criterion(outputs, y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    # Monitor the parameter updates
    for name, p in model.named_parameters():
        if name in ['out_task0.weight', 'out_task1.weight']:
            print(f"Controller: {controller}")
            print(name, p)
```

Did I miss anything in the training procedure? Or the overall setup will not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: the question has been answered from [PyTorch Forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/alternatively-train-multi-task-learning-model-in-pytorch-weight-updating-question/95346/3), I put things together here in case someone runs into the same problem, the credit goes to ptrblk*

The problem could arise from any variants of stochastic gradient descent(sgd) which utilizes gradients from previous steps, for instance, stochastic gradient descent with momentum(sgd-m), Nesterov accelerated gradient (NAG), Adagrad, RMSprop, Adam and so on. Zero-ing gradient at step `t` would not affect the terms relying on historical gradients. Thus the weights are still updated with the setting in the posted question.

One can see that from the following code example.

```py
model = nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False)

#optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1., momentum=0.) # same results for w1 and w2
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1., momentum=0.5) # w2 gets updated
#optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1.) # w2 gets updated

w0 = model.weight.clone()

out = model(torch.randn(1, 1))
out.mean().backward()
optimizer.step()
w1 = model.weight.clone()

optimizer.zero_grad()
print(model.weight.grad)
optimizer.step()
w2 = model.weight.clone()

print(w1 - w0)
print(w2 - w1)
```

With the native SGD optimizer, w2 and w1 are the same. But it is not the case for SGD-M and Adam.